# onEdit can programmatically create a trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I wrote a simple script trying to programmatically create a script from the onEdit function

```
function onEdit() {
  test();
}

function test() {
  triggerLater();
}

function customMsgBox() {
  Browser.msgBox("hello world");
}

function triggerLater() {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 1);
  try {
    var oneTimeOnly = ScriptApp.newTrigger("customMsgBox")
      .timeBased()
      .at(date)
      .create();
    return oneTimeOnly.getUniqueId();
  }
  catch (e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.toast("error");
  }
}
```

If I try to run onEdit from the script editor the trigger is created but every edit on the spreadsheet get a "error" message in a *toast*

Can someone help me to understand ?

Comment: FYI, if you toasted the value in the variable "e" you'd be able to see the exact error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onEdit` simple event handler function has limited permissions (i.e. it can not send emails, open the calendar, etc). Because it runs without the users permissions. Therefore, it can not set up a trigger (which do not have any restrictions and would be a huge security bug).

If you expected that the trigger should be created under your account, use the installable on edit trigger. First, rename your onEdit function to something else (so it is not triggered as a simple event handler), then go to the Resources menu and pick your function to run on spreadsheet edit events. Take a look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events) for more.

Comment: There's no info about triggers creation specifically. But the 3rd bullet point about simple event handlers says that nothing that require the user authorization can be done, which includes it. And it is kind of obvious that you should not be able to trigger an privileged code from an limited one. This would be a huge security issue.

Comment: There is specific info on the Security page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_security where it says "Simple events such as onOpen, onEdit, and onInstall execute under the identity of the user operating the spreadsheet. Installable events (spreadsheet triggers) execute under the identity of the user who created the triggers."