# Permissions for functions in Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am using a new feature of SpreadSheet in Google Sheets: 
"Named and protected ranges". In this range of protected cells, I use arithmetic built-in functions and my own written functions. 
The trigger to run my functions is on edit spreadsheet.

Users with write permissions, sharing the link of the spreadsheet, can't properly run my functions for permissions problem while built-in functions run properly.

Own can I grant permissions for my functions to run as Google Sheets built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in functions (Google Spreadsheet functions) have nothing to do with your triggered functions (made by you). You're complicating the explanation with 2 things that have nothing in common. Of course Google functions will work!

Please explain better **your** functions, are they triggered by what? onEdit, onOpen, a menu? What protected ranges have to do with it? Does your functions work if you remove the protection of your ranges?

**[edit]**

Simple event handlers (like onEdit) have limited permissions by design, you probably need to set a installable on edit trigger. Please check out this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736454/onedit-can-programmatically-create-a-trigger/10736686#10736686) I gave.

Comment: Sorry I press the return Key ! My function colors cells according criteria. The function is triggered by "on Edit" and the function works fine without protection of ranges.