Getting error "Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action." with Apps Script
I've been trying to get a script from Apps Script to work with a specific Google Sheets whenever a certain column cell is changed, but for some reason, the script just returns "Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly || https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds)" whenever said cells are changed.
I tried adding "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"] to my appsscript.json file, and I made sure that I and everyone else of whom the Google Sheet is shared with has access to the calendar that is being modified. Neither have worked so far. With that, here's the code (with major simplification):
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e!=undefined) {
    if (e.range.getColumn()>25) {
      let eventRow = e.range.getRow();
      let mySheet = e.range.getSheet();
      let myData = mySheet.getSheetValues(eventRow,1,1,29)[0];

      if (dt.sendInviteStatus) {

        CalendarApp.getCalendarById ("c_literallythecalendarID@group.calendar.google.com").createEvent(
          dt.eventName+" at "+dt.location,
          "Thu Aug 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)",
          "Thu Aug 01 2024 00:01:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
        );
      }
    }
  }
}


If you are executing your function onEdit as a simple trigger, how about renaming it to installedOnEdit and installing the OnEdit trigger to installedOnEdit and testing it again? By the way, can you provide your current oauthScopes?

Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I flagged your question as a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/10736454
